# How can I add color to console input/output?

Tags: python, colors

I want the prompt strings to be one color, and the user input to show in another color.

```
Date=input ("Date: ")
Market=input ("Market: ")
Price=input ("Price: ")
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/1515394

Answer (score 0):

Just like print colored text:

```py
Date = input("\033[94mDate:\033[92m ")
Market = input("\033[94mMarket:\033[92m ")
Price = input("\033[94mPrice:\033[92m ")
```

Or you can use bcolors like this:

```py
import bcolors
Date = input(bcolors.BLUE + "Date:" + bcolors.OK)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Both works well.